# A list of 100 or more classes to be instantiated on call

Tags: actionscript-3

Suppose this is the list of 100 or more classes :

```
var abc:Abc ;
var def:Def ; 
var ghi:Ghi ;
var jkl:Jkl ;
..
..
..
..
..
var xyz:Xyz ;
```

Now I want to instantiate the 1st set of 100 classes. How can I do it using an array within a for loop?

Comment: Use reflection: http://www.graniteds.org/public/docs/2.3.0/docs/reference/en-US/html/graniteds.reflection.html#reflection.call

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this?

You can pass around the class name like any old object, so I think you could do something like this -

```
var classes:Array = new Array();
classes.push(Abc);
classes.push(Def);
classes.push(Ghi);
// etc

for ( var classIndex:int = 0; classIndex < classes.length; classIndex++ )
{
    var klass:Class = classes[classIndex];
    var obj:klass = new klass():
}
```

Comment: However i got a a clue using getDefinitionByName function. But this was also helpful. Thnx!